# How to use UIAutomator to add account without using the index or x,y coordinate?

Tags: android-uiautomator

I am using a Nexus 5 device at the moment.

I am trying to click the "Remove Account" on screen.  I used the UIAutomatorViewer tool and found out about the Node Details for all the elements on the screen.  There are three elements that corresponds to the "Add account" that I am looking at.

Here is the layout hierarchy:
    (1) LinearLayout[468,265][1056,509]
    -(0) RelativeLayout[516,400][1008,473]
    --(0) TextView:Remove account[516,400][1008,473]

(1) LinearLayout[468,265][1056,509]
index    1
text    null
resource-id    null
class    android.widget.LinearLayout
package    com.android.settings
content-desc    null
clickable    true

(0) RelativeLayout[516,400][1008,473]
index    1
text
resource-id
class    android.widget.LinearLayout
package    com.android.settings
content-desc    null
clickable    false

(0) TextView:Remove account[516,400][1008,473]
index    0
text    Remove account
resource-id    android:id/title
class    android.widget.TextView
package    com.android.settings
content-desc    null
clickable    false

Ideally, I would like to implement this by clicking on the element that has the text "Remove account" but this is not possible because that element is not clickable.
    UiObject nextButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Remove account"));

Alternatively, I could refer to the clickable element by its index and className
    UiObject nextButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().index(1).className("android.widget.LinearLayout");
or refer to the x,y-coordinates
    getUiDevice().click(600, 450);
However, these 2 methods likely would induce maintenance cost down the road.

This is one of the most basic screen on Android.  I expect that there should be a better solution than what I posted here. Does anyone have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to use `getFromParent()` to find `TextView` element's parent UI element in hierarchy which in our example is `LinearLayout` and click it:

```
UiObject nextButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Remove account"));

UiObject parent =nextButton.getFromParent(new UiSelector().new UiSelector().className("android.widget.LinearLayout");
parent.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

Comment: Is there a typo?  Do you mean
UiObject parent = nextButton.getFromParent(....) instead of 
UiObject parent = playVideo.getFromParent(....)

Comment: Yes typo.. Sorry for the confusion.. corrected Answer..!!

Comment: Is "new UiSelector().new UiSelector()" a type also?